# jQueryUI Accordion treats <script> as part of output

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

Consider this code snippet:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>TEST</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   <script>some JS code </script>
</div>
```

Once accordion is initialised, JS code is becoming a part of output. I can see that  is being added some accordion attributes. How do I make accordion to ignore  as part of visible data and keep it as a script instead?

My code is auto-generating each accordion panel and some JS functionality is built as part of it, hence the problem.

Thanks,
Rudolf

Answer (score 0):

Why is it one comes up with an answer right posting on the forum?

Anyway, my solution is:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>TEST</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   <script class="ignore">some JS code </script>
</div>

<script>
  $( function() {
   $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    header:'h3:not(.ignore)'
  });
```

Not sure if this is a good way, but seem to work.
I am open to suggestions on a better way to implement what I need.

Rudolf